# How to return to the parent function in a nested functions inclosure that also has a return type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I realized when I created the question title that this question is difficult to properly convey to someone. So let me explain please.

Basically I have a function that requires a return statement in this case it's a Bool. Now inside of this function. I have another function that requires a separate return as well. I want to be able to call the return statement for the main/parent function inside of the Nest one.

**Code:**

```
func ParentFunction() -> Bool {

  // This function represents a real function where you have a to have a return type. 
  // So in other word you can not take off the fact that you have to have a -> String.
  func MyNestedFunction() -> String {

    // Here is where you would return the nested functions statement
    // but I'd rather not return the string and just end everything and return the Bool from the parent function
    return "Hello"

    // This is the parent functions return here I want to be able to stop any other process that the ParentFunction might do and just return here.
    return true

  }

    // This is the parent functions return as well.
    return true
}
```

** More of the actual Code here:**

```
   func MyFunction() -> Bool {
    tagger.enumerateTags(in: tagger.string!.startIndex..<tagger.string!.endIndex, unit: .paragraph, scheme: .nameTypeOrLexicalClass) { (tagResult, tokenRange) -> Bool in
        if let tag = tagResult, tag == "nil" {
            print("Found")
        }
        return true
    }
    // I would like it If we have already printed found in the function above then don't continue on to this function below
    tagger.enumerateTags(in: tagger.string!.startIndex..<tagger.string!.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .nameTypeOrLexicalClass) { (tagResult, tokenRange) -> Bool in
        if tagResult != nil {
            print("Found")
        }
        return true
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the details of your `enumerateTags` function, but since it has a `completion handler` you should add one to your function, and call it from the `completion handler` from the `enumerateTags` function.

```
       func MyFunction(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        tagger.enumerateTags(in: tagger.string!.startIndex..<tagger.string!.endIndex, unit: .paragraph, scheme: .nameTypeOrLexicalClass) { (tagResult, tokenRange) -> Bool in
            if let tag = tagResult, tag == "nil" {
                print("Found")
                completion(true)
            }
            return true
        }
        // I would like it If we have already printed found in the function above then don't continue on to this function below
        tagger.enumerateTags(in: tagger.string!.startIndex..<tagger.string!.endIndex, unit: .word, scheme: .nameTypeOrLexicalClass) { (tagResult, tokenRange) -> Bool in
            if tagResult != nil {
                print("Found")
                completion(true)
            }
            return true
        }
      }
```